# What happens when popToRootViewController is called?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uinavigationcontroller

Say I have a stack 3 view controllers deep. If I call `popToRootViewController` on the `navigationController`, the top view controller gets `viewWillDisappear` called but not on the middle controller. Is anything called on the middle controller?

Update: I tried to use dealloc for what I needed but found out that the VCs are deallocated from root+1 to top and not the way you would think a stack would work.

Comment: The middle controller never appears while popping to the root and it can't disappear when it never appears, so you wouldn't expect those methods to be called.  It will likely have its `dealloc` method called after it gets popped though.

Comment: The 2nd view controller's `viewWillDisappear` is supposedly called before the 3rd appears/is pushed. Similarly, if you push several view controllers at once one could expect that the "middle" controllers are not to call `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDisappear` until the navigation stack changes appropriately.

Comment: Yeah, I get that `viewWillDisappear` would not be called because the nav pops straight from top to root, but I would think it would notify the view controllers they are about to be popped from the stack.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `popToRootViewController`, the currently visible viewController disappears (after calling `viewWillDisappear`) and the **first** controller on the stack is shown.
All `viewControllers` in between are deallocated (after calling `dealloc`) without being shown. And if they are not shown, they can't disappear.

**TL;DR:** Use the `dealloc` method to handle anything you have too. (and make sure to not keep any strong references to those `viewControllers` anywhere)

Comment: I tried to use `dealloc` but it wasn't being called in top-down order of the stack so I couldn't use it. Instead I subclassed the `UINavigationController` because I already had a custom nav bar, and overrode `popToRootViewController` to call protocol methods on the VCs in the array returned by the super, in reverse order. it worked out